# g++ 10 doesn't recognize <compare>

Tags: c++, g++, c++20

I just installed g++10 on my computer, which runs the Ubuntu OS. These are the commands I used to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gcc-10
```

After everything was done, I tried compiling a basic program that used the spaceship operator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <compare>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Testing: " << (1 <=> 2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I got the compiler error

`fatal error: compare: No such file or directory`

that refers to `<compare>`. This confuses me, because according to the [Cppreference Compiler Support Page for C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), `<compare>` should be supported by g++10.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think your code will compile. You can't print a value of the type returned from `<=>`.

Comment: I recommend adding the compiler command line to the question. Since parts of C++20 are still being implemented it's likely that g++ is defaulting to C++14 or C++17. If you want C++20, you'll have to ask for it (`-std=c++20`).

Comment: You also need libstdc++ 10

Comment: Seems to "work" with g++-10: https://godbolt.org/z/aee7rz . Try `sudo apt-get install g++-10` instead of installing `gcc-10`

Comment: You need to use the right compiler. You will have several compilers installed by now. By default, Ubuntu does not use GCC10. So, try compiling with the command `g++-10` instead of just `c++`. Do not forget to specify `--std=c++20`